# How to change the size of the arrow in vue-tour?

Tags: css, vue.js, user-interface, vuetify.js

I am not able to change the arrow size in vue-tour. While I am able to change it by inspecting in Chrome, in CSS I am unable to do it as it has some runtime generated ID associated with it.

```
.v-step__arrow[data-v-e97491e4], .v-step__arrow[data-v-e97491e4]:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: inherit;
}
```

The v-step GitHub is available here: https://github.com/pulsardev/vue-tour/blob/master/src/components/VStep.vue

Comment: Are you declaring the css in the v-step.vue directly or declaring it in a component where you are using v-step as a child?

Comment: The vue-tour is a npm. I am using it in my own Vue Application. I can not figure out how to change the size of the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `v-deep`. It helps in applying the styles to the child-components directly.

If you are making use of `sass` then you can apply styling as:

```
::v-deep .v-step {
    background-color: black;
}
```

If you are simply using `css` then you can use v-deep as:

```
>>> .v-step {
    background-color: black;
}
```